# having problem with nested quote. Is there a software that auto fix them for you?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I always encounter a problem with nested quote, I think it's my 8th time that I encounter this in different projects. I can solve 2 levels of nested quotes but more that that. my code will not work. Is there a Generator or Software that will fix nest quotes for you?

here's my code.

```
  var noScript = '<noscript><meta http-equiv="' + 'refresh" content="0;' + 'url=' + 'http://ad.leadbolt.net/noscript?section_id=925516760' + '" />' + '</' + 'noscript>'

  function addLB() {

    jQuery('#footer').append('<script type="text/javascript">ap_loaded = false;' + '</' + 'script>' + '<script type="text/javascript"' + 'src="http://ad.leadbolt.net/show_cu.js?section_id=925516760">' + '</' + 'script>' + '<script type="text/javascript">' + 'if (!ap_loaded) { window.location =' + ' "http://ad.leadbolt.net/adblock?section_id=925516760"; ' + '}</' + 'script>' + noScript);
  }

  jQuery('.entry-artwork a.player').click(function(){ setTimeout(addLoading,100); setTimeout(addLB,5000) });
```

It's workin on Mozilla, but it isn't in chrome. it think the problem is with my nested tags.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: I think you misunderstand what noscript is.

Comment: To see (roughly) where the problem lies (with the JavaScript), I can recommend [JS Lint](http://jslint.com). Hint: there's two missing `;`

Comment: I don't think it is so much having a tool as understanding what you are doing in context of the browser and how it will attempt to parse what you have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try sepearting your script tags to

```
'<' + 'script type="text/javascript">'
```

Some browsers try to parse what you have as an actual script include.